# Salesforce Tracking just like in Marketing Cloud

Tags: salesforce

Just to ask if there's a Salesforce functionality wherein we can track email send time,open rate, clickthrough rate just like in Marketing Cloud?

[image]

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/pardot-email-marketing

Answer (score 2):

Marketing Cloud offers the ability to send tracking, click, bounce, unsubscribe, etc data back into Salesforce at the individual and aggregate levels. From there, you can create SF reports rather than rely on Marketing Cloud...However, this requires Marketing Cloud Connect.

Do you have Marketing Cloud Connect integration set up?